# Support Smart TV for android

Tags: android, smart-tv

I have been developed cinema android application in java  that show some movies and series the application is work very good
know I want to make that app work on smart TV is there is any way to do that or should I develop another app specified for TV

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately most of Smart TV are based on web technologies (HTML5, CSS JavaScript) but some manufacturers have been including Android TV as TV platform (Sony, Phillips, Thompson...)

Depending of your development, you can migrate directly (or making few changes) your current app to the Android TV requirements

For other TV platforms, like LG (webos) Samsung (Tizen) etc you will need to create your app using HTML, CSS, JavaScript and use the SDK to access native functions

BR